# Unable to catch TCP Client Error within try catch block | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, tcp, error-handling, thrift, es6-class

I am using a thrift client to make a request to a remote server in nodejs. However I am stuck at one point.

This is how I init my client connection & execute Tcommand

```
    try {
      const TClient = Thrift.getThriftClient()
      const status = await TClient.runCommand(expCommand)
    } catch (error) {
      throw error  // I need exception to be caught here.
    }
```

In the Thrift.getTriftClient() method, I use

```
 getTriftClient () {
    const thriftClient = thrift.createClient(command, this.getConnection())
    return thriftClient
  }


getConnection () {
    const connection = thrift.createConnection(this.host, this.port, {
      transport: this.transport,
      protocol: this.protocol
    })

    connection.on('error', (err) => {
      logger.error(scriptName, 'Thrift connection error', err)
      throw new Error('Not able to catch this in try catch')
    })

    return connection
  }
```

Now my problem is I am unable to re throw any exception which I encounter in error event listener block. What I want is to catch the exception in the first error block instance.

Is there somehow I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  const TClient = Thrift.getThriftClient()
  const status = await TClient.runCommand(expCommand)
} catch (error) {
  throw error  // I need exception to be caught here.
}
```

The try / catch block way of Error handling is for synchronous code.

The async / await way of Error handling is for asynchronous code.

You have got an await operator, inside of an AsyncFunction instance (async function), therefore you have async code, therefore you are working with Promises, Promises will either resolve to a value or reject with probably an Error instance.

Instead of synchronous:

```
try {
  const TClient = Thrift.getThriftClient()
  const status = await TClient.runCommand(expCommand)
} catch (error) {
  throw error  // I need exception to be caught here.
}
```

Do asynchronous:

```
const TClient = Thrift.getThriftClient()
.then((client) => {
  return TClient.runCommand(expCommand);
})
.then((commandResult) => {
  console.log(commandResult);
})
.catch((err) => {
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: The error is still not getting caught in the catch block

Comment: I am wondering if there is some way I can wait for the error event?

Comment: Does TClient.runCommand(expCommand); return a Promise or not? If it does, and this Promise rejects with an Error instance, this Error instance bubbles to the .catch method at the 'end' of the Promise chain.